# From Klein-Gordon equation to Dirac equation: a wrong "derivation"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, metric-tensor, commutator, dirac-matrices

So let us start with the Klein-Gordon equation
$$\tag{KG}
(-p^\mu p_\mu + m^2)\phi = 0
$$
The idea is to "factorize" the operator $-p^\mu p_\mu + m^2$.
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
-p^\mu p_\mu + m^2 = (-\alpha_\mu p^\mu - m)(\beta^\mu p_\mu - m)
= -\alpha_\mu\beta^\nu p^\mu p_\nu + m (\alpha_\mu p^\mu - \beta^\mu p_\mu) + m^2
\end{equation}
In other to retrieve $\mathrm{(KG)}$ it is hence necessary that

I. $-\alpha_\mu\beta^\nu p^\mu p_\nu = -\delta^\nu_\mu p^\mu p_\nu$

II. $\alpha_\mu p^\mu - \beta^\mu p_\mu = 0$

From II., since $x_\mu y^\mu = x^\mu y_\mu$, we get $\alpha^\mu=\beta^\mu$.  The unknown is hence one, let us rename it $\gamma^\mu$.

Considering now I.,
$$\tag{2}\gamma_\mu\gamma^\nu=\delta^{\nu}_\mu$$
or equivalently,
$$\tag{3}\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu=\eta^{\mu\nu}$$
where the right-hand side is the metric tensor operator
$$
\eta^{\mu\nu}:=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I have been informed that all this is wrong. For example, **all gamma matrices would commute with one another**, for the symmetry of the matrix tensor $g^{\mu\nu}=g^{\nu\mu}$:
$\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu = \eta^{\mu\nu} \overset{(3)}{\implies} [\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]=0$
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where is this derivation from? Your eq. (I) does not imply your eq. (2)., the correct relations leading to eq. (I) are the well-known anti-commutator relations $\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\} = 2\eta^{\mu\nu}$ you should find in *any* treatment of the Dirac $\gamma$-matrices.

Comment: It's just my attempt to recover the relation $\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\}=2\eta^{\mu\nu}$, without knowing it beforehand.

Comment: The problem is your $p^{\mu} p^{\nu}$ is symmetric in $\mu$ and $\nu$ because they commute, while $\alpha_{\mu} \alpha_{\nu}$ is not symmetric (they don't commute), so it has to be re-written in a symmetric way $\alpha_{\mu} \alpha_{\nu} = \frac{1}{2} \{\alpha_{\mu} ,\alpha_{\nu} \} + \frac{1}{2} [\alpha_{\mu} ,\alpha_{\nu}]$, where the anti-symmetric part cancels out (when contracted against the symmetric $p^{\mu}p^{\nu}$ term, which you should check explicitly). Thus your (2) and (3) are wrong.

Comment: Is it always possible to write any product $\alpha_\mu\alpha_\nu$ as the sum of its symmetric and anti-symmetric parts?

Comment: Yes it is. Prove it.

Comment: Ok, but @bolbteppa why is this decomposition necessary? Shouldn't the product $A B$, make sense regardless of the symmetry of each operator ($A$ and $B$ in this case)? Why shouldn't it be possible to compute such a product anyway?

Comment: An easier way to say it: $\alpha_a \alpha_b p^a p^b = \frac{1}{2} \alpha_a \alpha_b p^a p^b + \frac{1}{2} \alpha_a \alpha_b p^a p^b = \frac{1}{2} \alpha_a \alpha_b p^a p^b + \frac{1}{2} \alpha_b \alpha_a p^b p^a = \frac{1}{2}( \alpha_a \alpha_b + \alpha_b \alpha_a )p^a p^b$
where I just re-labelled dummy indices in the 2nd equality then used symmetry of $p^a p^b$ in the 3rd equality, now the 'coefficient' of $p^a p^b$ is symmetric just like $p^a p^b$ is, $p^a p^b$ knocks out the anti-sym part of $\alpha_a \alpha_b$ so only the sym part has to be equal to $\eta_{ab}$ for consistency.

Comment: The Dirac equation cannot be derived from the Klein-Gordon equation, as the latter does not describe spin. Whether a wave function is a spinor, a vector or a scalar, it will obey the Klein-Gordon equation as long as special relativity applies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conclusion (2) from I,
$$
(\gamma_\mu  \gamma_\nu -\eta_{\mu\nu})p^\mu p^\nu  =0     \tag{I}
$$
is unwarranted. This equation does not constrain at all the antisymmetric piece of
$$
\gamma_\mu  \gamma_\nu= \tfrac{1}{2} \{\gamma_\mu , \gamma_\nu\}+  \tfrac{1}{2} [\gamma_\mu , \gamma_\nu], 
$$
as @bolteppa reminds you in his comment, since that piece, the commutator, is projected out by tracing with a symmetric tensor (of the *p*s). So
all you get is just
$$
 \tfrac{1}{2} \{\gamma_\mu , \gamma_\nu\}-\eta_{\mu \nu}=0 \tag{2}
$$
instead of your expression.